# TableViewRow of variable height in Android

Tags: android, titanium, tableview, appcelerator

I am working with Appcelerator Titanium Studio, classic project.
In a window, there is a tableview consists of tableviewRow created one by one. One of these row contain only a ImageView which has a hyperlink as image source.
Since the size of the image is unknown, I have fixed the width of it:

```
ImageView.width=200;
ImageView.height=Ti.UI.SIZE;
```

It work on iOS but not on Android.
On window open (portrait), the image is shrink to a smaller size, definitely not 200. But if change device's orientation to landscape, it's width resume to 200, and the row height expand automatically. Then it keep maintain the correct image width and row height even change back to portrait.

Here is complete code snippet:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({});

var data = [];
var imageView = Ti.UI.createImageView({
 image:'http://images.bergdorfgoodman.com/ca/3/product_assets/T/B/F/Y/U/BGTBFYU_mk.jpg', 
 width:200, 
 height: Ti.UI.SIZE
});
var imageRow = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
  height:Ti.UI.SIZE
});
imageRow.add(imageView);
data.push(imageRow);
var tableview = Ti.UI.createTableView({data:data});
win.add(tableview);
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't using scaleType property for ImageView as below :

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImg"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

It will fix the width and height of ImageView to 300 and 400 respectively.

Programmatically :

```
ImageView view = new ImageView (this);
view.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

Comment: This is not Appcelerator Titanium is native's Android

Answer (score 0):

I would try setting the `postlayout` event on the image (http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ImageView-event-postlayout) and set the row height (parent of the image) to be what you get in the event parameter.

Another option is to use the `load` event of the `ImageView` (http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ImageView-event-load) and set row height to the current size of the image.

Answer (score 0):

My approach on this was the following:

Row view (Alloy):

```
<Alloy>
    <View id='row'>
        <Label id='title'/>
        <TextArea id='description'/>
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

Row style (Alloy):

```
"#row"{
    height:Ti.UI.SIZE,
    layout:'vertical'
}
"Label":{
    height:Ti.UI.SIZE
}
"TextField":{
    height:Ti.UI.SIZE,
    editable:false
}
"TextArea":{
    height:Ti.UI.SIZE,
    editable:false
}
```

On the row controller (Alloy) file I set that values and text properties, ex:

```
$.title.text = args.title;
$.description.value = args.value;
```

Then, at the end of the row controller (Alloy) I have this:

```
$.row.height = $.row.toImage().height;
```

In your case:

```
imageView.height = imageRow.height = imageView.toImage().height;
```

Answer (score 0):

Workaround aside, it looks like you've found something that works differently across platforms where it shouldn't need to. Please check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.